# can't append elements with jquery to data requested with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to append a button to copy code inside every `div` that has a class starting with `language`. It is currently working but I tried to get the data from database with Ajax and after I did the Ajax thing the button dosen't appear in the `div` like before Ajax so how can I do that?

**My code**

JS

`$("div[class^='language-'],div[class*=' language-']").append('<button class="CopyClipboard">Copy Icon</button>');`

AJAX requested data

```
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<div class="language-php">
   <code>echo 'hello World';</code>
</div>
```

it should be like this

```
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<div class="language-php">
   <code>echo 'hello World';</code>
   <button class="CopyClipboard">Copy Icon</button>
</div>
```

hope you understand 
sorry for my english :)

Comment: put your ajax code too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your question you import the div with class language-php via AJAX at some point after the page was fully loaded, your javascript code that append the button does it only once (very likely during or right after your page loaded). What you need is an event (onclick, onchange, ...) that trigger your append or put your code in the AJAX success callback.